# JavaScript Json Array foreach?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to parse this json data into lists on my site. However I can't seem to loop. I've looked online and nothing seems to work...

JsonData:

```
{"amount":4998,"users":[{"id":"765","username":"test","profileURL":"http://example.com","avatarURL":"http:///example.com"},{"id":"765","username":"test","profileURL":"http://example.com","avatarURL":"http://example.com"}]}
```

I want to loop users and then get id, username etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I've looked at that but because of the first part the amount, I can't seem to do obj.users and loop that...

Comment: Then loop through obj.users?

Comment: Whenever I do that it comes up with nothing. Its just blank data...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
obj.users.forEach(function(user) {
  console.log(user.username);
});
```

With a basic for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.users.length; i++) {
    var user = obj.users[i];
    console.log(user.username);
}
```